# Formatando valores com NumberFormatter() Swift

Tags: swift

Tenho uma função que desejo formatar os valores para decimais com o padrão brasileiro.
Hoje minha função está assim ...

```
func formatNumberToDecimal(value:Double) -> String {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
        numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = "."
        return numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:defaultValue)) ?? "Valor indefinido"
}
```

Mas ela retorna com um valor no formato *EN* por exemplo:

```
formatNumberToDecimal(1000.00)
// retorna o valor -> 1.000,00
```

Gostaria de saber como posso transformar para *pt_br* com duas casas após a virgula. No exemplo acima ele deveria retornar *1.000,00*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe `NumberFormatter` possui uma [propriedade `locale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1416967-locale), que pode ser atribuída para customizar o `Locale` usado como base nas formatações de números.

[Segundo sua documentação](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale), `Locale` é uma classe que possui convenções linguísticas, culturais e tecnológicas que devem ser usadas para formatar valores para exibição.

Desta maneira, você pode atribuir o locale desejado na instância de `NumberFormatter` que está usando, e fazer o seguinte para obter a formatação correta para "pt_BR", como você deseja:

```swift
func formatNumberToDecimal(value:Double) -> String {
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

    // Atribuindo o locale desejado
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")

    // Importante para que sejam exibidas as duas casas após a vírgula
    numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2 

    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal

    return numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:value)) ?? "Valor indefinido"
}
```

Comment: Formatter tem um method chamado `string(for: Any)` que voce pode passar um Double direto pra ele. Não tem necessidade de criar um objeto NSNumber `numberFormatter.string(for: value) ?? "Valor indefinido"`